# Remove a zsh plugin which enables this

Tags: zsh

I have configured my zsh konsole and it looks like this when kde terminal is started

```
[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected.

When using Powerlevel10k with instant prompt, console output during zsh
initialization may indicate issues.

You can:

  - Recommended: Change ~/.zshrc so that it does not perform console I/O
    after the instant prompt preamble. See the link below for details.

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly and prompt will update smoothly.

  - Suppress this warning either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

  - Disable instant prompt either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=off

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start slowly.

  - Do nothing.

    * You will see this error message every time you start zsh.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

For details, see:
https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#instant-prompt

-- console output produced during zsh initialization follows --


               MMM.           .MMM
               MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
               MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM      ______________________________________
              MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM    |                                      |
             MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   | Mind your words, they are important. |
            MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   |_   __________________________________|
            MMMM::- -:::::::- -::MMMM    |/
             MM~:~ 00~:::::~ 00~:~MM
        .. MMMMM::.00:::+:::.00::MMMMM ..
              .MM::::: ._. :::::MM.
                 MMMM;:::::;MMMM
          -MM        MMMMMMM
          ^  M+     MMMMMMMMM
              MMMMMMM MM MM MM
                   MM MM MM MM
                   MM MM MM MM
                .~~MM~MM~MM~MM~~.
             ~~~~MM:~MM~~~MM~:MM~~~~
            ~~~~~~==~==~~~==~==~~~~~~
             ~~~~~~==~==~==~==~~~~~~
                 :~==~==~==~==~~
    ~ ▓▒░······················································································································░▒▓ 0.94   28%   3.81G   0B   at 06:30:51 AM  ─╮
❯
```

I want to remove this part but can't figure out which plugin enabled it.

```
               MMM.           .MMM
               MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
               MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM      ______________________________________
              MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM    |                                      |
             MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   | Mind your words, they are important. |
            MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   |_   __________________________________|
            MMMM::- -:::::::- -::MMMM    |/
             MM~:~ 00~:::::~ 00~:~MM
        .. MMMMM::.00:::+:::.00::MMMMM ..
              .MM::::: ._. :::::MM.
                 MMMM;:::::;MMMM
          -MM        MMMMMMM
          ^  M+     MMMMMMMMM
              MMMMMMM MM MM MM
                   MM MM MM MM
                   MM MM MM MM
                .~~MM~MM~MM~MM~~.
             ~~~~MM:~MM~~~MM~:MM~~~~
            ~~~~~~==~==~~~==~==~~~~~~
             ~~~~~~==~==~==~==~~~~~~
                 :~==~==~==~==~~
```

Does anybody know how this part can be disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable that with add this or edit:

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet
```

to your `~/.p10k.zsh` if you use Powerlevel10k theme on zsh